# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 when posting multipart

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, multipartform-data

I am trying to do a multipart call in C# from windows phone.
I am sending the exact same json of a working android call but from wp I am getting this response body:

*"errorNumber":90 - A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of "}*

The first char I am sending is {.

Why does it happen?

Here is my code:

```
   public async Task postHttpClient(string serviceUrl, string requestObj)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("postHttpClient");
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            Debug.WriteLine("requestObj: " + requestObj);
            Debug.WriteLine("curly brace should be expected: " + (int)requestObj.Trim().ElementAt(0));
            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var contentData = new StringContent(requestObj.Trim());
            content.Add(contentData);

            var responseVar = await client.PostAsync(serviceUrl, content);
            responseVar.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Debug.WriteLine("responseVar: " + responseVar.ToString());

            var body = await responseVar.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("body: " + body);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("e: " + e.ToString());
        }

    }
```

and my fiddler:

- Raw Headers

  POST /MyServer/SendActivity/ HTTP/1.1
  Accept: */*
  Content-Length: 703
  Accept-Encoding: identity
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="e8763d7d-a53d-4baa-a6c7-c3bc37bd52a6"
  User-Agent: NativeHost
  Host: merp.techmobile.eu:8080
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Pragma: no-cache
- Textview tab

  --e8763d7d-a53d-4baa-a6c7-c3bc37bd52a6
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
  Content-Disposition: form-data

  {"SendActivityRequest":{"activity":{...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help someone to know that I fixed it by adding a key to my json,

By changing this line: `content.Add(contentData);`
to this `content.Add(contentData, "request");`